# Rewrite url of different pages to the same url in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, codeigniter-3

I want to rewrite url in codeigniter

For Products pages I want to change from given url

```
www.example.com/services/service-name
```

TO

```
www.example.com/service-name
```

For Services pages I want to change from given url

```
www.example.com/products/product-name
```

TO

```
www.example.com/product-name
```

But links are not working. It is not differentiating between products and services url. It get confused that whether the url is related to products or services. which particular page should be fetched.?

Comment: What is in `routes.php`?

Comment: Currently this is written in routes
$route['(:any)']     =   'controller-name/services/$1';
$route['products/(:any)']     =   'controller-name/products/$1';
when I change "$route['products/(:any)']     =   'controller-name/products/$1';" to
$route['(:any)']     =   'controller-name/products/$1';
it gives error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, wildcard route must be at the end

```
$route['some-route'] = 'ctrl/m/$1';
$route['some-other-route'] = 'ctrl/m2/$1';
...
$route['(:any)'] = 'ctrl/m3/$1';
```

[because](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#wildcards):

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

Second, having difference in route is good way to go because

1. If you don't have segment such as `/services/` or `/products/` you need to pay attention on insert not to duplicate name between different areas (i.e. services, products).
2. Even if you make your code check both tables on insert assuring you didn't duplicate name between services and products you would still need to query both tables each time wether you need service or product.

Routing works in a way value is taken from URL and application is going to do something with that value. If you have route

```
https://www.example.com/making-powerplant
```

application doesn't know if making-powerplant is service or product. So if you made everything on insert data or on insert `making-powerplant` to avoid doubling that title from services and products, now your application should query both tables. First it should query services table to see if there is title like that one. If title is not found in services table, application would need to query products table. That would be verbose app and code design since in most cases you are making query that you don't need. 
But that is only way you check two tables or two sources from one URI segment.
I would stick with `/services/service-1` and `/products/product-1`.